# Подставлять uri как параметр, если нет запрашиваемого файла

Tags: nginx, чпу

Расширения `.php` скрыл.

Нужно, чтобы при запросе вида
`site.com/username` *nginx* начал сначала проверять, есть ли файл вида `username.php`, и если нет такого файла, то подставлял в ссылку вида `site.com/profile.php?user=username`

Ну и так по ходу проверял наличие файла, и если файла нет, то как переменную подставлял.

На Апаче это должно выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Как это сделать для *nginx*?

Comment: в документации ведь отличные примеры: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, уточнив, что именно у вас не получается сделать, какие получаете ошибки и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться таким примерно *location-ом*:

```
location ~ ^/([^.]+)$ {
  try_files $uri.php /profile.php?user=$1 =404;
}
```

---

см. [документацию и примеры к директиве *try_files*](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)